# passing fields collection into assembly method

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS 2008 R2 report with some custom code that operates on multiple fields from the dataset. To simplify calling it (two parameters instead of 8), I pass the Fields collection into the function like:

```
Public Function BPLatest(whichBP as String, Fields as Fields) as Integer
```

Since I just realized I need that code in another report, I thought I could create a custom assembly in C# 2010 Express, rather than cutting-and-pasting it. However, the searching I've done to this point leads me to believe that I can't use the Fields collection in an assembly, even passed in as above. Is this actually the case? If not, what's the proper syntax to use?

Comment: What language are you going to be working with, C#? The code you posted looks like vb.net. Also, you are using the class name as identifier (Fields as Fields) you probably just made a typo here but it should be 'fields As Fields'.

Comment: What assemblies are you using?

Comment: I'd probably be using C#, since that's what I have handy, but I might use VB. The above code is the VB code I'm currently using within SSRS. I don't really know what assemblies I'm using, that's why I'm asking. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Running the expression `=GetType(Fields).FullName` tells me that type is `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Fields`

It is defined in `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel.dll`

As far as I know objects in Fields collection are very dynamic, they are meaningful only in the scope of invocation.

Overall passing whole `Fields` collection into the custom code is not recommended.